# Trigger static_assert even when function signature is invalid

Tags: c++

Suppose I'm designing a library that provides some types and a template function that I expect users to instantiate on those types. The signature of the template function depends on nested typedefs within the template parameter, and I want to use `static_assert` to give a nice error message if the template is instantiated with an incompatible type:

```
// library.h
#include <type_traits>

struct compatible_with_f {};

struct foo : compatible_with_f {
  using some_type = int;
};

struct bar : compatible_with_f {
  using some_type = float;
};

template <typename T>
void f(typename T::some_type param) {
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<compatible_with_f, T>::value,
                "the template parameter to f should be `foo` or `bar`");
  // some code, which also uses the type T itself directly
}

// main.cc

int main() {
  f<foo>(0); // works
  f<bar>(0.f); // works
  f<int>(0); // error: no matching function for call to 'f'
}
```

This doesn't work as I hope: my friendly error message doesn't get printed, because the signature of `f` doesn't make sense, so the compiler bails out before it even reaches the `static_assert` in the body of the function.

Is there a way to achieve what I want in a good way? Here is the best I could come up with:

```
// library.h
#include <type_traits>

struct compatible_with_f {};

struct foo : compatible_with_f {
  using some_type = int;
};

struct anything {
  template <typename T>
  anything(T&&) {}
};

template <typename, typename = void>
struct get_some_type {
  using type = anything;
};

template <typename T>
struct get_some_type<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<compatible_with_f, T>::value>::type> {
  using type = typename T::some_type;
};

template <typename T>
void f(typename get_some_type<T>::type param) {
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<compatible_with_f, T>::value,
                "the template parameter to f should be `foo` or `bar`");
  // some code, which also uses the type T itself directly
}

// main.cc

int main() {
  f<foo>(0); // works
  f<int>(0); // error: the template parameter to f should be `foo` or `bar`
}
```

I use SFINAE to provide a default `some_type` which is convertible from anything. Now the signature always makes sense, so the compiler instantiates the body of the function and I get the nice error message. But I don't like this solution: it seems overly complicated, and it has the big disadvantage that the signature of `f` is now much less clear - before it took `T::some_type`, which was obvious, now it takes some weird trait magic. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a forwarding function to do the check before passing it to the actual implementation:

```
template <typename T>
void f_impl(typename T::some_type param) {
  // some code, which also uses the type T itself directly
}

template<typename U, typename T>
void f(T&& t)
{
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<compatible_with_f, U>::value,
                "the template parameter to f should be `foo` or `bar`");
  f_impl<U>(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/CCG42875)

EDIT:

Alternatively, you could add a less specialized overload for `f`:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T param) {
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<compatible_with_f, T>::value,
                "the template parameter to f should be `foo` or `bar`");
}

template <typename T>
void f(typename T::some_type param) {
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<compatible_with_f, T>::value,
                "the template parameter to f should be `foo` or `bar`");
  // some code, which also uses the type T itself directly
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/PGIW35125)

Comment: The biggest drawback of my proposed solution was the signature of the public-facing API function becoming less clear. This seems even less clear than that.

Comment: @STU Well, at least it's simpler :) Also, I don't think that you can keep the signature clear and avoid function being removed from the resolution set due to SFINAE...